# How to add locationPreview icon of the certain location in iPhone app?

Tags: google-maps, iphone

I was wondering if it is possible to add an icon (or image) with selected location like it is shown on the attached picture (left top corner) to my app? Maybe such an image could somehow be captured from Google or there is another way to deal with it? Any idea?

[Exmple http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/8376/img0044z.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/8376/img0044z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the MKMapView with a small frame size to accomplish this.

Comment: Sure, I also know about this great opportunity ;-) But, what about size of the pin? If I use MKMapView pin will be very big. Do you think Apple use small version of pin?

Comment: You could create a UIImage of the view and then resize the image  down.